# Does getbean() method share the beans for different instances of the bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, ioc-container

I have written a program to resolve circular dependencies using setter-based dependency injection. But the output is somewhat confusing.

**CODE**

```
package com.spring.core.di;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.spring.core.di")
class CoolAppConfig {

}

@Component
class DependencyA {
    DependencyB dependencyB;

    public DependencyA() {
        System.out.println("I am constructor of Dependency A");
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void setDependencyB(@Qualifier("dependencyB") DependencyB dependencyB) {
        System.out.println("I am setDependencyB !");
        this.dependencyB = dependencyB;
    }

    public void say() {
        this.dependencyB.who();
    }

    public void who() {
        System.out.println("I am Dependency A");
    }
}

@Component
class DependencyB {
    DependencyA dependencyA;

    public DependencyB() {
        System.out.println("I am constructor of Dependency B");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDependencyA(@Qualifier("dependencyA") DependencyA dependencyA) {
        System.out.println("I am setDependencyA !");
        this.dependencyA = dependencyA;
    }

    public void say() {
        this.dependencyA.who();
    }

    public void who() {
        System.out.println("I am dependency B");
    }
}

public class CircularDependencyIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CoolAppConfig.class);

        DependencyA dependencyA = applicationContext.getBean(DependencyA.class);
        DependencyB dependencyB = applicationContext.getBean(DependencyB.class);

        dependencyA.say();
        dependencyB.say();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I am constructor of Dependency A
I am constructor of Dependency B
I am setDependencyA !
I am setDependencyB !
I am dependency B
I am Dependency A
```

In the main method I have created an instance of `DependencyB`. Now my question is, When we are creating `DependencyA` bean first, it will output `"I am constructor of Dependency A"` and after resolving the `DependencyB` will also output `"I am constructor of Dependency B"`.

Now when we are creating the bean of `DependencyB`, why the constructor of `Dependency B` not called? I mean `"I am constructor of Dependency B"`, this should be printed twice in the output, but is present only once.

Does that mean, the beans/objects are shared among `dependencyB` and the object created while resolving dependency of `dependencyA`?

How does this flow working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Bean scope is Singleton, so only a single spring-managed instance will live for each class.

You could try adding a `@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` to one of your instances to see your expected behavior.

For more information, this Baeldung page may be helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

Answer (score 0):

The default scope is a Singleton so only one object will be created hence, the constructor was called only once.
Life cycle of a bean:
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-bean-life-cycle/
implement BeanFactoryPostProcessors, BeanPostProcessor for checking when exactly the beans were created.